# Treeviews QueueDraw doesn't render current row?

Tags: mono, treeview, gtk, gtk#, cellrenderer

I'm working with a treeview, which contains several columns, also one displaying a pixbuf, if audio is playing or paused. If the user double clicks on one row, audio playback starts and the row needs to be rerendered in order to display the pixbuf icon. I used QueueDraw for this, but that does only work, if the cursor leaves the current row. How can I update the pixbuf directly?

CODE:

```
protected void trvMainCuesheetRowActivated (object o, RowActivatedArgs args)
    {
        log.debug("trvMainCuesheetRowActivated called");
        TreeIter ti = TreeIter.Zero;
        this.lsCuesheetData.GetIter(out ti,args.Path);
        if (this.lsCuesheetData.GetValue(ti,0) != null)
        {
            Track tCurTrack = (Track)this.lsCuesheetData.GetValue(ti,0);
            if (this.objProgram.getAudioManager().getPlayState() == AudioCuesheetEditor.AudioBackend.PlayState.Stopped)
            {
                this.objProgram.getAudioManager().play(tCurTrack);
                this.refresh();
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.objProgram.getAudioManager().getPlayState() == AudioCuesheetEditor.AudioBackend.PlayState.Playing)
                {
                    this.objProgram.getAudioManager().seek(tCurTrack);
                    this.refresh();
                }
            }
        }
    }


private void renderPlaying(TreeViewColumn _tvcColumn, CellRenderer _crCell, TreeModel _tmModel, TreeIter _tiIter)
    {
        Track tCurTrack = (Track)_tmModel.GetValue (_tiIter, 0);
        //Just display an icon, if we are playing
        if (this.objProgram.getAudioManager().getPlayState() == AudioCuesheetEditor.AudioBackend.PlayState.Playing)
        {
            if (this.objProgram.getAudioManager().getCurrentlyPlayingTrack() == tCurTrack)
            {
                Gdk.Pixbuf icon = this.RenderIcon(Stock.MediaPlay, IconSize.SmallToolbar, null);
                (_crCell as CellRendererPixbuf).Pixbuf = icon;
            } 
            else
            {
                (_crCell as CellRendererPixbuf).Pixbuf = null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.objProgram.getAudioManager().getPlayState() == AudioCuesheetEditor.AudioBackend.PlayState.Paused)
            {
                if (this.objProgram.getAudioManager().getCurrentlyPlayingTrack() == tCurTrack)
                {
                    Gdk.Pixbuf icon = this.RenderIcon(Stock.MediaPause, IconSize.SmallToolbar, null);
                    (_crCell as CellRendererPixbuf).Pixbuf = icon;
                }
                else
                {
                    (_crCell as CellRendererPixbuf).Pixbuf = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                (_crCell as CellRendererPixbuf).Pixbuf = null;
            }
        }
    }

//Purpose: Function used to refresh the MainWindow depending on new options set.
public void refresh()
{
    //QueueDraw is needed since it fires a signal to cellrenderers to update
    this.trvMainCuesheet.QueueDraw();
    this.sbMainWindow.Visible = this.objProgram.getObjOption().getBShowStatusbar();
    this.mwToolbar.Visible = this.objProgram.getObjOption().getBToolbarVisible();
}
```

Greetings
Sven

Comment: Mind posting some code?

Comment: There you go ;). You can also check the svn at [link](http://sourceforge.net/p/audiocuesheet/code/HEAD/tree/)

Comment: No README? I get 283 errors and 5 warnings when trying to compile (either from project root or src dir) using `mdtool build AudioCuesheetEditor.sln` on Fedora 20 x86_64. Same for using `monodevelop` IDE.

Comment: Note that I am C# beginner especially when it comes to build tools.

Comment: Readme can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/p/audiocuesheet/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/AudioCuesheetEditor/README.TXT mdtool is currently not supported, if you want to build from console, you should try xbuild. I'm developing on fedora 20 and windows Vista and I'm using monodevelop and xamarin studio.

Comment: No one any idea? I would like to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error myself.

```
this.objProgram.getAudioManager().getCurrentlyPlayingTrack()
```

didn't always return a track, where I expected one, so the renderer worked right. Bug is fixed, thanks anyway ;).